# SpecialCells causing SheetSelectionChange event in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-addins, vba

I have a test Macro

```
Sub test()
    Dim rSrcMatrix As Range
    Set rSrcMatrix = Sheets("Code Matrix").Range("Xfer_To_Xfer_Matrix").Range("A1")
    Set rSrcMatrix = rSrcMatrix.Resize(rSrcMatrix.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, rSrcMatrix.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column)     
End Sub
```

I am using this macro to test my *COM* addin that I have created in VS2010. I have delegated the `SheetSelectionChange` event in the addin to some function.

Now I notice that whenever I run this macro, Excel fires the `SheetSelectionChange` event 4 times and my addin calls the associated method for that many times.

Is there anything that I am missing or is this a bug in excel?

Comment: Have you switched off events? Just answered this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662955/vba-excel-using-currentregion-without-selectionchanged-firing

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to work!!. But we are just disabling the events temporarily using this workaround. I still don't understand why "SpecialCells" would fire the event.

What if we wanted to associate another event with that line of code. In that case, we cannot suppress the event.

Comment: I believe and I could be wrong because I couldn't find an MSDN article to prove it but SpecialCells performs a type of selection and triggers the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event and hence you get that message. I am still looking.

Comment: I can give you an alternative code to the above for which you don't need to switch off event?

Comment: Hmm interesting. But I use 'Application.SheetSelectionChange' in my C# addin code. Is that in any way connected to 'Worksheet_SelectionChange'?

Comment: Yes. There are two kind of events for selection change. One which you can trigger off from the sheet code area and the other from the `Thisworkbook` code area. What you have in C# is the `ThisWorkbook` equivalent which is `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange`. BTW, like I mentioned in my last post, are you open for an alternative?

Comment: Do you have any other alternative apart from the one you gave in the first comment? Otherwise, since I don't have any other option, I will go ahead with the solution that you provided to me.

Comment: Yup I have.. gimme few moments :)

Comment: Posted an answer. BTW good question +1 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe and I could be wrong because I couldn't find an MSDN article to prove it but SpecialCells performs a type of selection and triggers the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` or the `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` event and hence you need to switch off events.

Here is a simple way to test it.

Place this code in the Sheet Code Area

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "Damn! The SpecialCells caused me to pop up!!!"
End Sub

Sub test()
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
End Sub
```

`Worksheet_SelectionChange` and `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` do the same job. `Worksheet_SelectionChange` is used in the sheet code are for a specific sheet. And `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` is used when you want the event to fire across all the sheets in that workbook.

> **YOUR QUESTION FROM THE COMMENT**: What if we wanted to associate another event with that line of code. In that case, we cannot suppress the event.

Now, we have two alternatives. Based on your above question we cannot use `Alternative One`. So you may directly skip to `Alternative 2`

**ALTERNATIVE 1**

Switch Off Events

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    '
    '~~> YOUR CODE
    '

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

**ALTERNATIVE 2**

Instead of using `SpecialCells` to find the last row or the last column, we will use `.Find`.

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rSrcMatrix As Range
    Dim Lrow As Long, LCol As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Code Matrix")

    With ws
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            Lrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row

            LCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Column
        Else
            Lrow = 1
        End If

        Set rSrcMatrix = .Range("Xfer_To_Xfer_Matrix").Range("A1")
        Set rSrcMatrix = rSrcMatrix.Resize(Lrow, LCol)

        Debug.Print rSrcMatrix.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: nice idea, but actually the cell returned by the first Find method call is the same than the next: with xlPrevious, the first looked up cell in a searched range is actually the same no matter xlByRows or xlByColumns (except if After is set to something else than the first cell in the searched range)

Comment: and xlCellTypeLastCell method returns the last cell no matter if empty or not, while the Find method (as is) can only return the last non empty cell (the latter will be wrong if the last cell of a Worksheet.UsedRange is empty but has some formatting)

Comment: your solution can actually find the last non empty cell in range, my solution can find the last empty cell in a range, but I fail to find a unique solution without comparing row and column numbers of the 2 found cells...

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Siddharth Rout technique, here is a method that will return the last cell of a `Worksheet.UsedRange` (see my comments below his answer)

```
Function GetLastCellEmpty(rng As Range) As Range
    Set m_rngCheck = rng

    Set m_rngFound = m_rngCheck.Find(What:="", _
                            LookIn:=XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas, _
                            Lookat:=XlLookAt.xlPart, _
                            SearchDirection:=XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious)
    Set GetLastCellEmpty = m_rngFound
End Function

Function GetLastCellUsedRange(ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Set GetLastCellUsedRange = GetLastCellEmpty(ws.UsedRange.Offset(1, 1)).Offset(-1, -1)
End Function
```