# Why am I getting a type mismatch error here?

Tags: vba, excel

I create a new module and insert this code:

```
Sub test()
   Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
   sCount = wsData.Columns(14).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
   msgbox sCount
End Sub
```

In the worksheet "Data", I have this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K:M")) Is Nothing And Target.Value <> "" Then
            'code
        End if
    End if
End Sub
```

When I run the `test()` sub, I get a type mismatch error on `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K:M")) Is Nothing`, as Target wrong type.

Why this is happening?

Why is test triggering the Change Event?
I dont get the same error if manually filter column 14 of my Data sheet to leave only the blank cells!

Comment: What happens if you try `Worksheets("Data").Range("K:M")` instead of `Range("K:M")`?

Comment: Why is `test` triggering the `Change` Event?

Comment: Can I suggest that you add what you intend for your code to do to your question? Also `wbT` is not defined in `test()`?

Comment: I wonder if `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` maybe triggers a filter on the sheet... do you get the same error if you manually filter column 14 of your Data sheet to leave only the blank cells?

Comment: @Tom `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` does trigger the `selectionChange` event. The selection is the blank cells. I knew it just 30 sec before :P

Comment: It's very simple actually :) Let me p ost an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with the type mismatch, is that the `Target.Cells` is more than one cell. Thus, the `Target.Value <> ""` throws type mismatch, because multiple cells cannot be compared to `""`. See the `MsgbBox` with the number of cells:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then MsgBox Target.Cells.CountLarge
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K:M")) Is Nothing And Target.Value <> "" Then
            'code
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Based on the business logic there could be several solutions.

- The easiest one is to write 
  `If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub` in the `_SelectionChange` event.
- Another way is to disable events around

`sCount = wsData.Columns(14).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count` like this:

---

```
Sub TestMe()
   Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   sCount = wsData.Columns(14).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   msgbox sCount
End Sub
```

Comment: May I suggest to use `Target.Cells.CountLarge` just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Storax - it is safer, yes.

Comment: I dont need here COunt, and at all triggering the Change Event from other function

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin - The `.CountLarge` is used as an illustration for answering the question *Why am I getting a type mismatch error here?*.

Comment: ++ Nicely Explained :)

Answer (score 1):

I almost closed this question as a duplicate.

I will answer both your questions but in the reverse order so that you can understand it better.

> Why is test triggering the Change Event?

I have explained it in [SpecialCells causing SheetSelectionChange event in Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663368/specialcells-causing-sheetselectionchange-event-in-excel-2010)

> When I run the test() sub, I get a type mismatch error on If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K:M")) Is Nothing, as Target wrong type.
>   Why this is happening?

When the procedure `Test` triggers the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event, your code will fail on the line

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K:M")) Is Nothing And Target.Value <> "" Then
```

It is because `Target.Value <> ""` is the culprit as `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count` may return multiple cells.

If you break the above line in 2 lines then you will not get an error

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K:M")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
             'code
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```