# Multiple select when running date selector tool and autofit with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a data entry Excel sheet to input patient information for a more streamlined follow up process.

I use the calendar selection tool for some columns.
I run an autofit for all columns.

I can get the multiple selection in a blank sheet, but not when combined with the other two.

For example, there are a set list of labs that could be collected from a patient.
The default data validation list mode lets you select a single element from a list, and then when you select a second element it will delete the first.
I am trying to make it so that if I select 1, and then select 2, both 1 and 2 will show in a single cell, instead of it deleting 1 and only showing 2.
Link to the instructions I used [Excel Data Validation - Select Multiple Items](https://www.contextures.com/excel-data-validation-multiple.html).

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Developed by Contextures Inc.
' www.contextures.com
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column = 26 Then
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
        & ", " & newVal
'      NOTE: you can use a line break,
'      instead of a comma
'      Target.Value = oldVal _
'        & Chr(10) & newVal
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  
  'DOB
  With Sheet1.DTPicker1
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 20
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
      .Visible = True
      .Top = Target.Top
      .Left = Target.Offset(0, 1).Left
      .LinkedCell = Target.Address
    Else
      .Visible = False
    End If
  End With
  
  'Date of Incident
  With Sheet1.DTPicker2
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 20
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
      .Visible = True
      .Top = Target.Top
      .Left = Target.Offset(0, 1).Left
      .LinkedCell = Target.Address
    Else
      .Visible = False
    End If
  End With
  
  'Medical Exam Date
  With Sheet1.DTPicker3
    .Height = 20
    .Width = 20
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K:K")) Is Nothing Then
      .Visible = True
      .Top = Target.Top
      .Left = Target.Offset(0, 1).Left
      .LinkedCell = Target.Address
    Else
      .Visible = False
    End If
  End With
  
  Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: "I can not get the multiple selection to work" - please include steps to reproduce the problem: what exactly is "multiple selection"?  - what is the user doing and how is the outcome different from what you want?

Comment: So for example, there are a set list of labs that could be collected from a patient. The default data validation list mode lets you select a single element from a list, and then when you select a second element it will delete the first. What I am trying to do is make it so that if I select 1, and then select 2, both 1 and 2 will show in a single cell, instead of it deleting 1 and only showing 2. Hopefully that explains a little better. Here is a link to the instructions I used if that also helps, https://www.contextures.com/excel-data-validation-multiple.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

[SpecialCells causing SheetSelectionChange event in Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663368/specialcells-causing-sheetselectionchange-event-in-excel-2010)

Calling `SpecialCells` triggers the `SelectionChange` event: that clears the undo stack before execution returns to `Worksheet_Change`, so your code isn't able to get the previous value.  You need to disable events before calling `SpecialCells`

FYI you can avoid calling `SpecialCells` using something like this:

```vb
'Does cell rng have validation?
Function HasValidation(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim vt
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no validation
    vt = rng.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0
    HasValidation = (vt = 3)
End Function
```

Comment: This gave me the fix I was looking for. Thank you so much for you help.